# make a trigger return a message mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to know if there is a way to throw a message from a trigger without interrupting it?

I have a trigger that checks the stock of an ordered product each time an order is made. If the stock is under the minimum stock the trigger should complete the order and inform the user that is running out of that product.

```
DELIMITER &&
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ControlPedidoCliente&&
CREATE TRIGGER ControlPedidoCliente BEFORE INSERT ON LineasPedidosCliente FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE existencias INT;
DECLARE cantidad INT;
DECLARE diferencia INT;
DECLARE total INT;
DECLARE stockMinimo INT;
SELECT (StockMaximo-PendServir) FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = NEW.IdProducto INTO existencias;
SELECT (PendRecibir-PendServir) FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = NEW.IdProducto INTO diferencia;
SELECT StockMinimo FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = NEW.IdProducto INTO stockMinimo;
SET cantidad = NEW.Cantidad;
SET total = (existencias + diferencia) - cantidad;
IF total < 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No hay suficientes existencias, se debe pedir';
END IF;
IF total < stockMinimo THEN
    /*THE MESSAGE SHOULD BE HERE*/
END IF;
END&&
DELIMITER ;
```

I've tried to call a stored procedure but i still get the "Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A random message from a trigger seems like a poor way to "inform a user", and I'd think _"Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger"_ would pretty much tell you "no, this is not allowed". A better solution might be to set up some sort of "notifications" table you could write such messages to, and have another process monitor.

Comment: I agree, Triggers cannot return values, however, they can manipulate records even in tables that the trigger is not working on.

Comment: @MB34 aside from the row the trigger is operating on, triggers can ONLY work on tables not involved in the triggering of the trigger.

Comment: You can do DDL in a stored proc from a trigger.

Comment: Sounds like you need a warning (`SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000'` and `MYSQL_ERRNO = 1000`) [SIGNAL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html)